# Create web-application in Python. What use?

Tags: python, web-applications

**Description problem.**
I would like to create my first internet application (more complex than those available in many tutorials).Future users will be able to these application only from my website. Something like Instagram (I read somewhere that it was written in Python) but much, much simpler... actually the website will be composed from simple gallery and chat with the administrator.

**Question**
1.) I've realize a little tutorials, but always in every big part of the page  is written in HTML and little in Django. Can I create the whole application using Python (or bigger part of these)? if yes what be useful to me (for sure Django, but what else?)?

2.) When i can use a [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/GettingHelp.html)? in internet is very few information of these, why? is it not practical? For me, an inexperienced person looks good.

I'm sorry if my question it is very general, but I'm not sure what to use to create this simple internet application on my website.

Comment: This is a very opinion based question and you are quite unlikely to get any answers based on anything else than opinions.

Comment: Experiment with available frameworks and see what suits you the best (in small projects) and then implement it in your main one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely have a look to these projects:

- [Bottle.py](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/): Very simple, not designed for very large applications
- [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/): An amazing framework for small and rapid prototyping. Can actually run very large applications if well done.
- [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/): A real killer machine, extremely powerful. A lot of things come out-of-the-box, can really speed up the development process. A bit more difficult to understand at start than the others.

It is very difficult to recommend any specific one, I would just say that depending on how complex is your application, you should orient yourself toward Django or Flask. If it is very simple, you can have a look to Bottle / Flask.

Django and Flask are the most known frameworks, they will ease your hiring process or finding freelances. And good tutorial exists.

Django have the most "out of the functionalities" which can be a very good point to quickly advance on your project.

Comment: Just a note.  I constantly see this idea that bottle is not setup for very large applications which has zero technical reasons.  Bottle does not come bundled with a ton of modules, but it is one of the fastest and most efficient web frameworks you can use.  There is no structural reason why bottle can't run the same apps as flask or django.  In fact I would argue django is one of the worst frameworks you can use in regards to development time, speed, and needless complexity.